# Assets folder issue

Tags: angular

I am creating roles in my Angular 4 Application, after creating a role successfully one JSON file is generated from back end ( JSON file contains List of Menu Items which user can access)
I am storing these JSON files in Assets folder. and i am using these files to build side menu.

but the issue is when i am trying to log in with new role(immediately after creating new role), side menu is not building even though the corresponding role's JSON file is exist in Assets folder. When i restart the lite server with ng serve and login with new role then side menu is showing. i.e., changes/ new updates in assets folder are not reflecting if we don't rerun the ng server in @angular/cli

but refreshing / restarting the lite server is not a good practice.

how to resolve it with out restarting the lite server.

Comment: Why do u have to store the menu list as a json file ?

Comment: Please share some code so we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi  @Outlooker , we  are storing menu as JSON because to build it dynamically as per role( role also created dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your JSON files out of the **assets** folder. The **assets** folder if for static files only, and whenever you add a file in that folder, you need to restart the cli.

Move the JSON files to another location and serve them with your webserver (nginx/nodejs/...)

Comment: Hi @David, Thanks for the solution