# Angular 8: assets not loading

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use (image) assets in a brand new angular (8.0.3) project.
I've looked into the [asset configuration](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#project-asset-configuration) from the docs. Judging by the information there it should work out of the box?

So I created an image folder and put a random .jpg image in there.

```
ls src/assets/images
paladin.jpg
```

```
ls src
app  assets  environments  favicon.ico  index.html  main.ts  polyfills.ts  styles.css  test.ts
```

angular.json *(this is all default)*

```
  "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
```

In index.html we have *(also default)*

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

app.component.html *(I changed the base64 logo with the assets image)*

```
<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="assets/images/paladin.jpg">
```

But nothing is loading or copies to the 'dist' directory.

The closest I've come to an answer are old threads:

- [Angular 5 images not loading from assets directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840734/angular-5-images-not-loading-from-assets-directory)
- [Assets folder issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001649/assets-folder-issue)

```
ng serve
ng build
```

Same result...even favicon.ico isn't loading...

I've tried:

```
<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="./assets/images/paladin.jpg">
<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="assets/images/paladin.jpg">
<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="../assets/images/paladin.jpg">
<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" [src]="assets/images/paladin.jpg">
<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" [src]="'assets/images/paladin.jpg'">
```

#### How to reproduce

```
ng new myTestApp
# => routing y/N doesn't matter
# => css option
ng serve --open
```

=> favicon gives 404

Am I missing something obvious here? :)

More info that might help:

```
$ ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 8.0.3
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.3
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.3
@angular/cli                      8.0.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.3
@schematics/angular               8.0.3
@schematics/update                0.800.3
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.30.0


$ npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\jonghena\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- @angular/cli@8.0.3

$ npm list --depth=0
my-test-app@0.0.0 D:\Gitprojects (GitHub)\angular-test\myTestApp
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.800.3
+-- @angular/animations@8.0.2
+-- @angular/cli@8.0.3
+-- @angular/common@8.0.2
+-- @angular/compiler@8.0.2
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@8.0.2
+-- @angular/core@8.0.2
+-- @angular/forms@8.0.2
+-- @angular/language-service@8.0.2
+-- @angular/platform-browser@8.0.2
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@8.0.2
+-- @angular/router@8.0.2
+-- @types/jasmine@3.3.13
+-- @types/jasminewd2@2.0.6
+-- @types/node@8.9.5
+-- codelyzer@5.1.0
+-- jasmine-core@3.4.0
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
+-- karma@4.1.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
+-- karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.0.5
+-- karma-jasmine@2.0.1
+-- karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.4.2
+-- protractor@5.4.2
+-- rxjs@6.4.0
+-- ts-node@7.0.1
+-- tslib@1.10.0
+-- tslint@5.15.0
+-- typescript@3.4.5
`-- zone.js@0.9.1
```

Full angular.json: https://pastebin.com/HaeKmQZ0

Comment: `src="/assets/images/paladin.jpg"` should work

Comment: It sadly doesn't, I just tried it again. But is it normal that out of the box, favicon.ico gives a 404 without me even changing any code ?

Comment: No it's not. After creating an app you could access to the favicon through `http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico` and to the image like this: `<img src="assets/images/paladin.jpg" />`. Did you change some Angular configuration?

Comment: So, after you do 'ng build --prod', and then look into the dist folder, you do not see an assets folder there?

Comment: @Mathias After "ng build --prod" my dist/myTestApp has no images/assets

Comment: @youri  after "ng serve --open" => http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico just returns me back to the homepage, havn't changed a thing to configuration. Because It returned me to the homepage I thought it could be a routing issue but a) its out of the box and b) it also has it when I opt for no routing when creating a project.

Comment: There are TWO "assets" sections in angular.json. Do you see the same in both? (just a double check)

Comment: As an FYI, the only time things will show in the dist folder is when you use 'ng build', ng serve does not place anything there.

Comment: @Mathias my full angular.json: https://pastebin.com/HaeKmQZ0 like i said I havn't touched it but I do see now that there are 2 sections, both are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be due to the parentheses in your workspace path: `D:\Gitprojects (GitHub)\angular-test\myTestApp`.

I don't know if the issue is reported in Angular's Github, but I suggest to check and report it.

As a workaround, you can remove your parentheses from your workspace path...

Comment: Indeed I just tried it and it fails with those "special characters" in the path.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the issue:

- 'my test'   => works
- 'my test(12)' => doesn't work
- myTestApp2 => works

So I think the culprit is the path: "D:\Gitprojects (GitHub)\angular-test\myTestApp"

Comment: Yes, that's it (as I answer just before you :)). It seems to be resolved in Angular 6 https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9852... Maybe you should reopen an issue on Github.

Comment: I've updated the issue on GitHub. At the very least I hope it saves someone a headache.

Comment: @youri, just wondering: if it was resolved in Angular 6 like you said, how did OP have a problem with it in Angular 8? Regression bug?

Answer (score 0):

I also had exactly the same problem on Angular 8, with loading local images,
with the `html`, `img`, `src` tags. In my case the project's path was absolutely fine: /home/1/app-spa

I had the `"src/assets"` in `angular.json` file, and put an `image 1.png` directly into the assets folder (with no subfolder there).

And surprisingly after running `ng-serve`, I could not see the image when trying to access it on Firefox Browser with url or img tag:

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/1.png
```

Getting 404 not found

However, exactly the same URL opened correctly on Chrome.

I found out that in my firefox browser I had disabled option to display local images, in the Page Info Settings (Ctrl + I) to access, as on the attached image. After changing this Firefox setting the image started to display properly, same as on Chrome. I took me half a day to figure this out.

[Firefox Page Info Settings][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv4Du.jpg